# Как запарсить соседний элемент в json?

Tags: php, json

Есть следующая json-строка:

```
{  
    "code":"IEV",
    "name":"Kiev",
    "coordinates":{  
        "lon":30.5,
        "lat":50.45
    },
    "time_zone":"Europe/Kiev",
    "name_translations":{  
        "en":"Kiev",
        "en-GB":"",
        "en-AU":"",
        "de":"Kiew",
        "zh-CN":"",
        "ru":"Киев",
        "tr":"Kiev",
        "en-CA":"",
        "en-NZ":"",
        "en-IE":"",
        "en-SG":"",
        "en-IN":"",
        "es":"Kiev",
        "fr":"Kiev",
        "it":"Kiev",
        "th":"เคียฟ ซุลฮานี่"
    },
    "country_code":"UA"
}
```

И есть переменная, которая содержит в себе строку "Киев". То есть, подходит к следующей строке:
`"ru":"Киев",` А мне нужно достать значение поля "code" в самом начале json-строки. Как это сделать? И как вообще обращаться к родительским элементам json-строки?

Comment: Никак. Просто запоминайте `code` в переменной перед тем как ничинаете искать город в `name_translations`.

Comment: Для более внятного ответа нужно знать как вы ищете слово "Киев".

Answer (score 0):

Для начала Вам нужно перевести строку в объект. Для этого в PHP есть функция `json_decode()`. Но на вход она принимает строку в `UTF-8`. Если у Вас строка в другой кодировке, то предварительно ее нужно перекодировать, вызвав, например, `iconv()`

```
$str = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $str);
$data = json_decode($json_str, true);
if (!$data)
  die(json_last_error_msg());
```

ну а дальше все просто - смотрим, есть ли искомая срока и выводим результат

```
$key = array_search('Киев', $data['name_translations']);    
if ($key !== false)
  echo $data['code'];
```

Comment: Написал следующий код: `$cities_json = file_get_contents('json/cities.json');
    $data = json_decode($cities_json, true);
    $key = array_search($geo['city']['name_ru'], $data['name_translations']);
    if ($key !== false)
     echo $data['code'];` и получил ошибки: `Notice: Undefined index: name_translations in /var/www/orders/skytickets/index.php on line 114

Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in /var/www/orders/skytickets/index.php on line 114

Notice: Undefined index: code in /var/www/orders/skytickets/index.php on line 116`

Comment: В общем говоря, если сделать вывод переменной $cities_json - то всё ок. А если обращаться конкретно к $data['name_translations'], то вывод будет NULL.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Скорее всего проблема в кодировке. Доуточнил ответ

Comment: если ставлю UTF-8 без BOM, то тогда в json-файле пропадают все иностранные кодировки, в том числе и русский. Если ставлю просто UTF-8, то тогда $data возвращает NULL. Что делать?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin какакая кодировка файла `json/cities.json`? Он должен быть в кодировке UTF-8 без BOM

Comment: если он в кодировке без BOM, то у меня появляются Notice: Undefined index. Как я уже описал выше, а с такой кодировкой пропадают все иностранные переводы названия городов(из-за этого я появляются Notice). Если делаю просто UTF-8, то выводится NULL. Я уже голову сломал над тем, почему так происходит.

Comment: мне всё ясно. Файл cities.json весит 2,4 мегабайта и json_decode просто крашится при попытке запарсить такой большой объём данных. Есть аналог json_decode?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Ваше предположение маловероятно. Посмотрите, что возвращает `json_last_error_msg ()`

Comment: в песочнице маленький кусок кода работает, а большой - уже нет. Попробовал сделать `echo json_last_error();`, что вывело мне просто цифру 4.

Comment: Попробовал сделать `json_last_error_msg()` и в выводе у меня `no errors`. Но это при том условии, если кодировка UTF-8 без BOM.

Comment: Тогда я вообще не понимаю, как эта хрень должна работать. UTF-8 с нормальной кодировкой видит данные, но почему-то их не парсит, а UTF-8 без BOM возвращает NULL.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin ` UTF-8 с нормальной кодировкой ` это как? UTF-8 это уже кодировка. Что обозначает Ваша фраза?

Comment: я уже объяснял. В файле содержаться переводы городов на разные языки, в том числе китайский, тайваньский и прочие. Если в json-файле поставить кодировку без BOM, то все эти переводы(включая русский) пропадут. Их не будет видно, если загрузить json-файл в браузере. А вот если поставить просто UTF-8, то в браузере всё будет отображаться нормально, но почему-то json_decode отказывается парсить такой .json-файл. Я уже шестой час голову ломаю.

Comment: При этом, var_dump выводит массив на экран, но доступ к `name_translations` я получить не могу.

Comment: по всей видимости, ваш код работает только в том случае, если массив одиночный. Если таких массивов много один за другим, то код работать не будет, так как полей **name_translations** будет более 4000 тысяч и код просто не будет понимать, какой ему элемент парсить. По этому, нужно искать не $data['name_translations'], а просто $data. Поскольку там 0 совпадений. Имя города на русском языке будет уникально. Осталось только понять, как получить доступ к **code**

Answer (score 0):

```
$city_code = json_decode($json_str);
echo $city_code->code;
```

`$city_code` - объект. Пройти по его свойствам можно с помощью `foreach`.